# Sleep command for every 10 objects processed in tcl

Tags: csv, tcl

I'm taking input from `csv` file and processing it in tcl. i have been trying to give some 2 minutes ***time gap*** for every 10 lines processed from csv. The csv may contain around 500 lines. So it needs some time for processing this. Below code is my try. I don't have any knowlegde on tcl, just googled and tried but this is not working.

```
set fileIn [open "/mydir/Test3.csv" r]
set i 0
while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
    incr i
    if{$i==10} {
     after 120000
     set i 0
     continue       
    }
    set lsLine [split $sLine ","]

    set sType [lindex $lsLine 0]
    set sName [lindex $lsLine 2]
    set sValue ""
    set sCount  [lindex $lsLine 3]
    set sprice [lindex $lsLine 4]

    # My other operations
}
```

Also let me know whether is it better to use `after` or `sleep`.

Comment: In what way is it not working? And by the way, why do you need to give it a "time gap"? I usually work with 200.000 - 600.000 line files, and I have never needed to slow the reading down. Lastly, parsing csv with split is an accident waiting to happen: use the csv module instead.

Comment: @PeterLewerin: 1) It is not giving the proper time gap. I gave **puts** inside the if loop. It took five minutes and still i didn't got the output. whether my code is correct?? 2) I need to call my application from tcl which takes times to process the objects. If it keeps on calling it will overload 3) Unfortunately We don't have csv module in the running environment :(

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is if you don't show the code that has the problem, e.g. the `puts` you mention. Are you saying that you are reading / processing asynchronously? In that case you probably shouldn't attempt to synchronize the processes by arbitrary delays; it would be better to use one or other of the real synchronization techniques (of which I unfortunately have very little practical experience), such as `vwait` or `send`.

Comment: "we don't have the csv module" -- you can just grab the source code and include it with your own code: http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spacing in Tcl is important. Your if statement needs a space after if.

```
if{$i==10} {
```

should look like

```
if {$i==10} {
```

Since you want to run this every 2 minutes you'll need to take into account the processing time of the first 10 items.

```
set fileIn [open "Test3.csv" r]
set i 0
set start_ms [clock milliseconds]

while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
    incr i
    if {$i==10} {
     set now_ms [clock milliseconds]
     set timetaken_ms [expr {$start_ms - $now_ms}]
     after [expr {120000 - $timetaken_ms}]
     set start_ms [clock milliseconds]
     set i 0
     continue
    }
    set lsLine [split $sLine ","]

    set sType [lindex $lsLine 0]
    set sName [lindex $lsLine 2]
    set sValue ""
    set sCount  [lindex $lsLine 3]
    set sprice [lindex $lsLine 4]

    # My other operations
    puts "$sType - $sName - $sValue - $sCount - $sprice"
}
```